Issue Integrating Monaco PromQL with Angular 11
I am trying to integrate Monaco PromQL into my Angular 11 project following the guidelines from the official documentation: Monaco PromQL Angular Integration.
Environment:
Angular Version: 11
Dependencies:

"monaco-editor": "^0.21.3"
"monaco-promql": "^1.7.4"
"@monaco-editor/loader": "^1.4.0"

After setting up the project according to the tutorial, I am encountering an issue.
enter image description here
The Monaco editor should initialize without errors, and the PromQL language features should be available.

please share the minimal reproducible code, if possible a stackblitz with the issue replicated

please edit your question and replace the error message image with the text of the error message itself. Never post images of code or error messages.
